# s3 object to read_csv error: (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I'm using airflow's s3Hook to get a list of all the keys, which I'm able to do but when I try to use pandas I get the following error. I think I need to find how to pass the creds I use for s3hook for pandas... if that makes sense?

The first error I see is:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

then

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

below is my code

```
def transform_pages(company, **context):
    ds = context.get("execution_date").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    s3 = S3Hook('aws_default')
    # s3_conn = s3.get_conn()
    keys = s3.list_keys(bucket_name=Variable.get('s3_bucket'),
                        prefix=f'S/{company}/pages/date={ds}/',
                        delimiter="/")

    prefix = f'S/{company}/pages/date={ds}/'
    logging.info(f"bucket_name_func: {Variable.get('s3_bucket')}")
    logging.info(f"prefix func: {prefix}")

    logging.info(f'keys from function: {keys}')

    """ transforming pages and loading data back to S3 """
    for file in keys:

        filepath = f"s3://{Variable.get('s3_bucket')}/{file}"
        logging.info(f'filepath : {filepath}')

        df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None)
```

Comment: look into the `storage_options` parameter in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @AsishM. fantastic, this worked for me!

Comment: What storage options worked for you ?

Comment: do we need to create different dictionary for storage_options or we can use something from s3_hook ?